# Можно ли развернуть картеж, чтоб передать его в качестве аргумента в функцию, где требуется несколько аргументов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Вот пример, у нас есть кортеж

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
```

есть функция

```
int calc(int a, int b, int c);
```

Могу ли я как то развернуть кортеж, чтоб передать его вместо 3 аргументов в функцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого в стандартной библиотеке есть вспомогательная функция `apply`:

```
#include <tuple>

int calc(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}

int main()
{
    return ::std::apply(::calc, ::std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3));
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%0Aint+calc(int+a,+int+b,+int+c)%0A%7B%0A%09return+a+%2B+b+%2B+c%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%09return+::std::apply(::calc,+::std::make_tuple(1,+2,+3))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g112,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: а с конструктором такое можно сделать?

Comment: Конструктор можно обернуть в функцию, возвращающую объект.